# How to cut 2D Mesh with polyline. Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am trying to find a way to split simple 2D mesh into two parts.
I have a mesh constructed from 4 or more points and I have a simple 2D poly line.
Poly line is nothing more than a series of nodes(Vector3) and edges.

I can detect intersection points between mesh and the line, but I can’t find a way to separate all points into two set?
Two sets of points have to be in order as I have ear clipping algorithm to make a mesh from them.

I am using Unity and C# but I think I will be able to script it if I know the right approach.

Here is a small sketch to illustrate what I want to get.
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/DanniSchou/MeshSplitting

Comment: Yes, I’v seen this. But it is not what I am asking.

Comment: In the case of a mesh made of more than 4 points, what should the output be ?

Comment: If I can have list of ordered points it would be great. I have made an ear clipping algorithm which will bye able to make a mesh for me

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that the intersection of the polyline and the edge between v1 and v3 (in the upper picture) isn't a vertex in the lower picture. Is it intentionally so?